# How to make jQuery post data to Controller and then return to another view page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a MVC project and I use jQuery to post data from my Index page to Home controller

from view page

```
function Search(){
var _name = document.getElementById("HotelName").value;

$.post("Search/", { name: _name });

}
```

In my controller

```
 public ActionResult Search(String name){   

 var Hotel = db.getHotelByName(name);

 return View ("Search",Hotel);  }
```

While debug data already pass to controller but i need it to render the view "Search" with Hotel object after finish posting.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you use a "regular" postback then?